# PHP REST webservice can't identify URL parameters from route

Tags: php, apache, rest, zend-framework

I can't supply parameters through URL in tesying.mywebsite.com to REST webservice implemented using ZF2. http://testing.mywebsite.com/dev/public/api/file/get-new-files/7c73c4193e98277d4dd1b7e0265ac374/52f328ff9ea1f
Here last two fields are parameters. It is working in localserver but in testing.mywebsite.com, parameters are not resolving and whole url is treated as resource url.  Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Sreekumar M K.

You might not have enabled the mod_rewrite module of the Apache server. 
Try the following:

> a2enmod rewrite

Restart apache2 after

> /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

or

> service apache2 restart

Let me know if this helps.

Sincerely,
Denis Rendler